# Доступ к объекту в документе из фрейма

Tags: javascript

Есть страница с iframe и javascript внутри iframe. 
Как изменить параметры объекта в документе (в частности высоту iframe) из-под java-скрипта фрейма?

Comment: случайно не это вы хотите? http://hashcode.ru/questions/5456/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%83-iframe

Comment: Проблема в том, что Java-скрипт находится не в самом документе, а в фрейме. И в зависимости от определенных данных внутри фрейма, он должен изменять свою высоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так. В родительском документе:

```
function resizeIframe(height) {
// Тут Вы пишете код для ресайза iframe на текущей странице
}
```

А в iframe пишите так:

```
<input type="button" value="Resize!" onclick="top.parent.resizeIframe(100);">
```

p.s: мог напутать с top.parent вложенностью вызова функции, т.е. может быть top.parent.document.resizeIframe. Нужно смотреть firebug'ом.

Comment: Не помогает. Пробовал оба варианта вложенности.

Comment: Сделайте alert в resizeIframe. И посмотрите ошибки firebug'ом.

Comment: Сообщение не появляется. Firebug выдает Permission denied for <http://hokmt.ru> to get property Window.document

Comment: Может домены разные?

Comment: Да, домены разные. А это как-то влияет?
UPD: Перенес все файлы на один домен. Всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно, влияет!)) Браузер в целях безопасности не дает возможности js обращаться к другим доменам без их ведома :) Поэтому (если необходимо использовать другой домен), то нужно приравнять домены в js: document.domain = 'mydomain.com'; Эту операцию необходимо сделать таким образом, чтобы приравнять домены обоих сторон.